# Retrieving the employees Rehired within a year from their termination date in peoplesoft/oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I have this table-

```
Empl id  Eff seq  EMP Name     Date         Action

20140531    1      abc         05-MAY-08      Hired 
20140531    1      abc         05-Jun-08      Termin 
20140531    1      abc         15-Dec-08      Rehired
20158888    1      XYZ         25-Jan-10      Hired
20158888    1      XYZ         05-MAY-10      Termin
20156666    1      BBB         12-Feb-12      Hired
20157777    1      AAA         05-MAY-13      Hired
```

So if we write the query on above database, it should return the EMPLID-

- 20140531

As this employee is rehired within a year from his termination date.
Wondering how we can get the results.

Comment: In your sample table why `XYZ` have same emplID = 20158888 on hired and termin, but `ABC` doesnt? is EmplID PK on that table or not? I think you should improve your table design. You need two table an `Employee` table and a `EmployeeHistory` table. Then `EMP Name` go only in `Employee` and `EmployeeHistory` only need  `EmplID`

Comment: actually, i have mentioned it correctly, the employee id, name for <20140531- should be abc>. As it shows the multiple actions on single employee,

Comment: EMP name `ABC` have thre diferent `Empl ID`

Comment: I have corrected my DB now, pls check. I do have one table only in which i do have actions (Termn, hired, rehired) and the multiple entries will be there, as each action will have one separate row

Comment: Hi juan, now pls check the DB :)

Comment: What is wrong with Bob answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLS(EMPLID       NUMBER,
                   Eff_seq      NUMBER,
                   EMP_Name     VARCHAR2(10),
                   ACTION_DATE  DATE,
                   Action       VARCHAR2(10));
```

and is populated with data as specified in your question then the following query will get you what you're looking for:

```
WITH REHIRED_EMPLS AS (SELECT *
                         FROM EMPLS
                         WHERE ACTION = 'Rehired'),
     TERMINATED_EMPLS AS (SELECT *
                            FROM EMPLS
                            WHERE ACTION = 'Termin')
SELECT DISTINCT r.EMPLID
  FROM REHIRED_EMPLS r
  INNER JOIN TERMINATED_EMPLS t
    ON t.EMPLID = r.EMPLID
  WHERE t.ACTION_DATE BETWEEN r.ACTION_DATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR
                          AND r.ACTION_DATE;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff41b/3)

Best of luck.

## EDIT

Updated query and SQLFiddle based on corrected data provided by OP.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks but i have corrected the DB, would be helpful if you can take a look at above comments i mentioned and corrected DB. As i am not having 2 different tables.

Comment: with the fix on db you dont need the HIRED_EMPLS sub query now. But i think the query is ok

Comment: Thanks Bob, can we implement this query in simple sql, i mean in select statement rather than using WITH, LAG and partition clause. IS it possible?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that does not require joins:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ceffae/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( Emplid, Effseq, EMPName, "Date", Action ) AS
          SELECT 20140531, 1, 'abc', DATE '2008-05-05', 'Hired'   FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL SELECT 20140531, 1, 'abc', DATE '2008-06-05', 'Termin'  FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL SELECT 20140531, 1, 'abc', DATE '2008-07-25', 'Interviewed' FROM DUAL 
UNION ALL SELECT 20140531, 1, 'abc', DATE '2008-12-15', 'Rehired' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 20158888, 1, 'XYZ', DATE '2010-01-25', 'Hired'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 20158888, 1, 'XYZ', DATE '2010-04-05', 'Termin'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 20156666, 1, 'BBB', DATE '2012-02-12', 'Hired'   FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 20157777, 1, 'AAA', DATE '2013-05-05', 'Hired'   FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Previous AS (
  SELECT EmplID,
         LAG( CASE WHEN Action = 'Termin' THEN "Date" END IGNORE NULLS ) OVER ( PARTITION BY EMPName ORDER BY "Date" ) AS PrevTerminationDate,
         "Date" AS CurrentDate,
         Action
  FROM   Employees
)
SELECT EmplID
FROM   Previous
WHERE  Action  = 'Rehired'
AND    CurrentDate <= PrevTerminationDate + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ceffae/5/0)**:

```
|   EMPLID |
|----------|
| 20140531 |
```

**Query 2 - No `WITH`, `LAG`, etc**:

```
SELECT EmplID
FROM   Employees e
WHERE  Action  = 'Rehired'
AND    EXISTS(
  SELECT 'X'
  FROM   Employees x
  WHERE  x.Action =  'Termin'
  AND    e.EmplID =  x.EmplID
  AND    e."Date" >  x."Date"
  AND    e."Date" <= x."Date" + INTERVAL '1' YEAR
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ceffae/5/1)**:

```
|   EMPLID |
|----------|
| 20140531 |
```

Comment: This solution will only detect Rehires that immediately follow Terminations.  It works for the data set provided, but would fail if there were some other action between Termin and Rehire.

Comment: @Sentinel Thanks for pointing that out - fixed it and also made it a bit simpler.

Comment: Thank u guys can we implement this query in simple sql, i mean in select statement rather than using WITH, LAG and partition clause. IS it possible?

Comment: @ABG - Yes (see query 2 in the edit) - but it's less efficient as it has to do a join (whereas the `LAG` version does not).

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function get the latest (or earliest) termination date in within the past year then only select those records with action`'Rehired'` that have a non null `last_term_date`:

```
with emps as (
select empls.*
     , max(case action when 'Termin' then action_date end)
           over (partition by emplid
                     order by action_date
                     range between interval '1' year preceding
                               and current row)
       last_term_date
  from empls
)
select emplid from emps
 where Action = 'Rehired'
   and last_term_date is not null;
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06df2/6)

Note: I added one record to show that rehires after one year don't get selected.

Comment: @Senetinel- thanks for the efforts, as per your guidance, i have molded the query in my DB and tried to execute it, but its been throwing me an error of-  ORA-00904: "LAST_TERM_DATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 12  This is the query that i have written-

Comment: With Employee as (
select ps_job.*, 
max(case action when 'Terminatn' then action_dt end)
over (partition by emplid
order by action_dt
range between interval '1' year preceding 
and current row)
last_term_date
from ps_job)
select emplid from ps_job
where action = 'Rehire'
and last_term_date is not NULL;

Comment: Try this instead: `WITH Employee AS
  (SELECT ps_job.*
  , MAX( CASE action WHEN 'Terminatn' THEN action_dt END ) 
    over( partition BY emplid order by action_dt range BETWEEN interval
    '1' YEAR preceding AND CURRENT row ) last_term_date
     FROM ps_job
  )
 SELECT emplid
   FROM Employee
  WHERE action        = 'Rehire'
  AND last_term_date IS NOT NULL;`  The only change is the second from clause.

Comment: @Sentinel- I tried, thanks to you it executed this time but didn't return any value on my DB nor on the Fiddle [Check it out in here-](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2cfc4/1)

Comment: Thank you, can we implement this query in simple sql, i mean in select statement rather than using WITH, LAG and partition clause. Is it possible?

Comment: @ABG Bob Jarvis avoids analytic functions in his approach, though he does use subfactored queries (the with clause), but that can be eliminated by moving the queries down into the main from clause.  You'll still have sub queries though.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment on my other answer you requested a method that avoids subfactored queries (the with clause, a.k.a. common table expressions) and which does not use analytic clauses such as LAG.  So here's a simplified version:

```
select distinct EMPLID
  from EMPLS E
 where Action = 'Rehired'
   and exists (select 1 from EMPLS T
                where T.EMPLID = E.EMPLID
                  and T.Action = 'Termin'
                  and t.Action_Date between e.Action_Date - interval '1' year
                                        and e.Action_Date)
```

with the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06df2/8) to boot.